# SEO impact of using <small> tag in <h1>

Tags: seo, html5

Twitter bootstrap uses `<small>` tag within `<h1>`. What is the SEO impact of this? Will the text content in the `<small>` tag get equal importance?

Here is an [example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs) (see the *Lightweight defaults Same markup, different classes*):

```
<h2>Lightweight defaults <small>Same markup, different classes</small></h2>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of usage?

Comment: I've added an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[What specifically happens as far as search engines' interpretations of these things is always going to be up for speculation. But:]

The text might be seen as slightly less important. Remember, though, that it's *still within an `H*` tag*, so we'd be talking slightly less starting from that context. [That would be correct](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/small.html) as it's intended to represent "fine print" or [side-line content](http://html5doctor.com/small-hr-element/). It would also be in keeping with its specific purpose in Bootstrap as "subtext" for the header.